# What is the easiest way to detect a cross-over in values of 1d list?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have two lists in Python:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # y values of a line
b = [7, 6, 4, 4, 8, 4] # x values are index location of the list

// result = [F, F, F, T, F, T]
```

Now if you can imagine these points represent 2 lines, a and b.
Line a just goes up linearly (albeit thats arbitrary), while line b comes descending down and first touches a where x=4, and than crosses over where x=6.

What I would like to do, is have a simple and Pythonic solution for detecting when lines touch or cross-over. I'm wondering if numpy or some other library can already do this.

EDIT:
I wrote this contraption, I think it works as far as detecting crossovers goes. `aa <= bb;aa >= bb` should make it detect touches too.

```
# check if lines crossed in past X bars
def cross(a, b, bars=3):
    aa = np.array(a[-bars:])
    bb = np.array(b[-bars:])

    if len(np.unique(aa < bb)) == len(np.unique(aa > bb)) == 1:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: you can change   `if len(np.unique(aa < bb)) == len(np.unique(aa > bb)) == 1:`  in  `(a>b).any() and  (b>a).any()` which is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the difference of the two lines.

```
difference=a-b
```

Then there is an intersection if the sign of difference change from an item to the next (it will be null on touch). you can have it like that :

```
cross=(np.sign(difference*np.roll(difference,1))<1)[1:]
```

`[1:]` is to discard the first point which is not relevant. cross is `True` if 
there is an intersection just before.

A complete exemple :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=np.random.randint(0,20,20)
b=np.random.randint(0,20,20)
plt.close()
plt.plot(a,'*-')
plt.plot(b,'*-')
difference=a-b
cross=(np.sign(difference*np.roll(difference,1))<1)[1:]
plt.plot(np.arange(.5,19),10* cross, 'd')
```

There is a red diamond each time the segments cross themselves. Touchs are considered as double contacts in this approach.

[image: crossing lines]

Comment: I love it. Implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

If the values of `a` and `b` at the same index are the same, then two lines touch, If the previous value of `a` is up on the previous value of `b`, and the current value of `a` is down to the current value of `b`, then two line is cross-over.  using `zip` to iterate `a` and `b` at the same time, and using a variable `previous` to store previous info.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # y values of a line
b = [7, 6, 4, 4, 8, 4] # x values are index location of the list

previous = 0
result = []
for x, y in zip(a,b):
    if x == y: result.append(True) #touch
    else:
        comapre_result = 1 if x > y else -1
        if comapre_result + previous == 0:#cross-over
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
        previous = comapre_result

print result
```